# Enviar Model Razor com $Ajax Serializada a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Estou tentando enviar um objeto para `controller`, utilizando `ajax`.

O objeto vai para a controller com `Json`, mas reconhece apenas os valores do do get, e não do post.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("AdiconarTeste", "Empresa")",
        data: {empresa:JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))} ,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success != false) {
                if (result.Url != null) {
                    $(location).attr('href', result.Url);
                } else {
                    divLista.html(result);
                    myModal.modal('hide');
                }
            } else {
                alert(result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

O objeto chega desta forma na controller:

```
{
"empresaID":0,
"cidadeID":null,
"objCidade":null,
"nome":null,
"endereco":null,
"bairro":null,
"numero":null,
"cep":null,
"telefone":null,
"fax":null,
"url":null,
"listaTelefones[
    {
    "telefoneID":0,
    "empresaID":null,
    "ObjEmpresa":null,
    "contatoID":null,
    "objContato":null,
    "tipo":3,
    "numero":"69 3226 6565"
    },
```

Obeservem que a lista está populada, isso é get da controller que foi realizado para populá-la.

Model:

```
public class Empresa 
{ 
    public int empresaID { get; set; } 

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")] 
    public int? cidadeID { get; set; } 
    public string fax { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name = "URL"), DataType(DataType.Url, [ErrorMessage = "Url inválida")] 
    public string url { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> listaTelefones { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Teste> listaTestes { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Como está o código do seu Controller?

Comment: Você colocou [HttpPost] acima da declaração do Controller?

Comment: public class Empresa
    {
        public int empresaID { get; set; } 

        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public int? cidadeID { get; set; }
   
        public string fax { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "URL"), DataType(DataType.Url,      [ErrorMessage = "Url inválida")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Telefone> listaTelefones { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Teste> listaTestes { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando JSON.stringify, então na verdade você não está enviando um objeto para o servidor, você está enviando é uma string. Remova o JSON.stringify, para que seus dados sejam enviados como JSON e não como string:

```
data: {empresa:@Json.Encode(Model)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar isso?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdiconarTeste", "Empresa", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Salvar()", OnComplete = "unlockPage()", OnBegin = "lockPage()", OnFailure = "ajaxHandleError" }, new { @id = "meuForm"}))
{
Coloque os inputs aqui
}
```